# UITextField.Text contents disappearing after pressing UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField which is populated with a value selected from a pre-defined UIPickerView. The selection of the value from the picker is working fine and the selected value is assigned to the .text of the TextField. The view also has a UIButton which performs validaiton on the contents of the TextFields. When the button is pressed and displays a warning via a UIAlert, after pressing OK the contents of the TextField which was set from the picker is cleared. Other TextFields which are set by the user entering values via the keyboard, are all working ok and they do not get cleared.

Can anybody suggest why this one style of TextField with a Picker to select a .text value, would be getting cleared when I press my Button and fire its action?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you have provided enough information to get help. I would expect to see your code for some of the methods you are referring to. Particular, what are you doing in the target action of the UIButton and the delegate methods of the UIAlert. Those would be my first suspects in your case.

Comment: Apologies all, it was mistake... I was inadvertantly clearing the textField contents myself by doing;

    if ((self.myTextField.text = @"something")) {

instead of;

    if ([self.myTextFueld.text isEqualToString:(@"something")]) {

Comment: I suspected as much. Glad to see you get it figured out.

Comment: Thanks Dean, and apologies for lack of technical detail in original question. I will remember for next time.

Comment: You should re-enter your solution in the answer field, then approve your own answer to make this post answered,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inadvertantly clearing the textField contents myself by doing;

```
if ((self.myTextField.text = @"something")) {
}
```

instead of;

```
if ([self.myTextField.text isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
}
```